# Vectors and a rhombus

Tags: geometry, vectors

The quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a rhombus. $\vec{AA_1}=\vec{BD}$ and $\vec{CC_1}=\vec{BD}$. The quadrilateral $ACC_1A_1$ is always: a trapezoid/a rhombus/a square/a rectangle.

[image]

Since $$\vec{AA_1}=\vec{BD}\\ \vec{CC_1}=\vec{BD}\\\Rightarrow \vec{AA_1}=\vec{CC_1}$$ which implies that $AA_1=CC_1$ and $AA_1\parallel CC_1,$ or $ACC_1A_1$ is a parallelogram. I don't know how to use the fact that $\vec{BD}$ is actually a diagonal in the rhombus $ABCD$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what you need to check (to determine rectangle-ness) is whether $\vec{AA_1}=\vec{BD}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{AC}$. Do you know a way to check whether two vectors are orthogonal?

Comment: @Arthur, Thank you for the response! I don't know what orthogonal vectors are.

Comment: $90^{\circ}$. Normal. Right-angled. There are many words for it. Do you know a way to check whether that's true for two vectors?

Comment: @Arthur, yes, we haven't studied this. :)

Comment: Well, then you need to decide whether the angle is right with some other (non-vector) geometric fact.

Comment: @Arthur, any hints on that?

Comment: @Medi Hint: See the fifth bullet point in the [rhombus characterizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus#Characterizations) section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular. Then $BD\perp AC$ or $AA_1\perp AC$. Thus $AA_1C_1C$ is a rectangle.

For a proof, let $ABCD$ be a rhombus whose diagonals intersect at $P$. Then $\angle ADB=\angle ABD$ and $\angle DCA=\angle DAC$ since $\triangle DAB$ and $\triangle DCA$ are isosceles. By parallelism, $\angle DAC=\angle DCA=\angle BAC$, so by $ASA$ we have $\triangle DAP\cong\triangle BAP$, and $AP\perp BD$ is now clear.

A vector proof: assume for simplicity that the rhombus is anchored at the origin, and so vertices are at the end of $\overrightarrow0,\overrightarrow A,\overrightarrow C$, and $\overrightarrow A+\overrightarrow C$. The vector representing the diagonal $AC$ is $\overrightarrow A-\overrightarrow C$ and the other diagonal is just $\overrightarrow A+\overrightarrow C$. To show two vectors are perpendicular, we want their dot product to be $0$. So
\begin{align*}
(\overrightarrow A+\overrightarrow C)\cdot(\overrightarrow A-\overrightarrow C)&=|\overrightarrow A|^2-\overrightarrow A\cdot\overrightarrow C+\overrightarrow C\cdot\overrightarrow A-|\overrightarrow C|^2\\
&=|\overrightarrow A|^2-|\overrightarrow C|^2\\
&=0
\end{align*}
since $|\overrightarrow A|=|\overrightarrow C|$ by rhombus.